# Netsuite Tax Item Script

Tags: field, netsuite

I have customers that have several ship to addresses in netsuite. My problem is this, each one of those ship to addresses needs a different tax item. So if I were to enter a sales order and select the customer, I need some way that when I select a ship to(from the drop down) the tax item is filled in with the correct one. I have yet to find a way to link a certain ship to address to a certain tax item, not to mention have it fill in once the ship to address is selected on a sales order. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it appears to be about how to use a program, rather than a programming question

Comment: This answer has to be with programming, there is no way to do this through the program. Has to be done with a script.

Comment: Then I suggest you put a bit more detail in here if possible.... I don't know anything about netsuite just trying to give you pointers to help you get an answer. Details about your form, anything you've attempted to script so far - people here are more likely to help if they can see what you've researched or attempted to do already.  Good luck.

Comment: Also, since netsuite seems rather 'specialist' rather than general purpose programming (which is the strength of StackOverflow) are there not any specialist forums or support groups you can find?  I'm not saying that no-one here will be able to help, but its certainly less likely than questions about more widely used platforms, there seem to be a question about it only every few days.

Comment: @iandotkelly instead of typing all those comments you could have answered someone else's question

Comment: @cja .... mmm so trying to help a new user, suggesting they add detail - such as the code - isn't constructive?  The purpose of one of the review queues is to help new users.

Answer (score 0):

If these tax items are just for your reference, then you can create a custom record type and store the reference shipto & taxitem. 
Then you can use client script to populate the taxitem based on the shipto by querying the custom record type.

Comment: I can't seem to think straight or something. I have an error I am trying to fix.
   object.setFieldValue('custbody_custom', 2);
I take the object out then no errors with internal ID
I put the object in then it says not a valid internal ID.
I am new but I can't seem to figure this one out. I have the code doing what I want except trying to populate it to a custom field.

Comment: If you can put the code then it will be more helpful to understand the problem